# JMeter non-GUI in Jenkins issue with Include Controller

Tags: testing, jenkins, jmeter, automated-tests

I have two scripts in my test. A_script.jmx with the main test plan and the test fragment B_script.jmx with the module.

To include B-script into A_script.jmx I use the Include Controller with a path to the B_script.jmx

All works fine when I work in GUI locally but when I try to run it in Jenkins in non-GUI I receive an error:

> Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException:
>   ModuleController:Notification has no selected Controller (did you
>   rename some element in the path to target controller?), test was
>   shutdown as a consequence

As I suppose the Include Controller in the A_script.jmx cannot find my B_script.jmx file here.
Should I use some special path format in my Include Controller FileName? Both scripts are kept in one directory. I tried "B_script.jmx", "../B_script.jmx" etc

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Comment: Does it work fine in non gui mode locally (without Jenkins)?